# Debian10: No such file or directory: /dev/dri/card0

Tags: debian, command-line, xorg, debian-installer, framebuffer

I'm installing Debian 10 but I cannot `startx` nor have a GUI. I think the problem is about some driver.

Here are the errors I've got in /var/log/Xorg.0.log :

1. [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0 - 19
2. open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
3. Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
4. Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section
5. Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs for all framebuffer devices.

If someone can help I will be extremely thankful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide what graphics card do you have and what login manager or desktop environment did you install.

Answer (score 1):

First, check your graphic cards:

```
$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
```

If your graphic card is made by AMD, install it from non-free:

```
# apt install firmware-amd-graphics
```

Answer (score 0):

stumbled accross the same issue. Turned out to be the non-free firmware missing (signalled in dmesg). after installing that lot it worked.